# Unable to Implement a Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to build on the job title column in the `employee_tbl`, which references the job title column in the `job_tbl`.  An “alter table” statement will be required to build this foreign key on the `employee_tbl`.

This is what I have and the message I am getting:

```
CREATE TABLE JobTitle
(
    Employee_Tbl int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,

    JobTitle int NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Job_Tbl(JobTitle)
);
```

Error message:

> ```
> Msg 1778, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Column 'Job_Tbl.JobTitle' is not the same data type as referencing column
>     'JobTitle.JobTitle' in foreign key 'FK__JobTitle__JobTit__29572725'.
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
> ```

Comment: what type is the type of Job_Tbl.JobTitle

Comment: If it is a foreign key.. How can it be null....

Comment: *"I am trying to build on the job title column in the employee_tbl"*. No, you are not. You have `CREATE TABLE **JobTitle**` (not `employee_tbl`)

Comment: @Maverick Foreign key columns are allowed to be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Check what the data type is of Job_Tbl.JobTitle. It is probably a varchar/char/other type. Your JobTitle.JobTitle is of type int. Normally on the foreign key it will match to the primary key of another table. If your primary key for Job_Tbl is an auto_number or ID file, then use that.

Comment: all I know is it is the jobtitle from both the employee_tbl and the job_tbl

Comment: I would advise to fully check your database tables and know what each columns data types are. This will help you in working with your tables and understanding the errors.

Comment: Thank you but I have figured it out